# Парсинг строки регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу правильно распарсить строку на составные части:

```
B09.863.020    материала методом полимеразной цепной реакции              4955.72         3 234         16 026 798.48
```

Вытаскиваю артикул `B09.863.020` с помощью:

```js
B\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}
```

А вот правильно вытащить цену `4955.72`, количество `3 234` и сумму `16 026 798.48` не получается.

Цена и сумма могут быть как с дробной частью, так и без неё.
Количество всегда только целое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: и по какому принципу вы хотите определить, что в строке `3 234 16 026 798.48` будет является количеством, а что суммой? Давайте для пущего чуть изменим строку на `300 234 160 026 798.48`

Comment: Там между группами большее число пробелов, от 5 и более. Тут не получается показать.

Comment: пробелов больше, или таки табуляции?

Comment: Это точно не tsv формат?

Comment: короче тут либо тупо по табам разбить надо, либо по `\s{2,}` и распихать по полям